# Linked-IN Reporting (Empty Elements Array Issue)

Tags: linkedin-api

It's been a couple of days now I'm facing BLANK array issue with the Linked-IN API (Reporting) returning me blank array response (Elements array is blank) and the count => 10 (default).

The Response:

{
"paging": {
"start": 0,
"count": 10,
"links": []
},
"elements": []
}

Steps that I have already verified:

1. Token is valid (Also checked with token inspector)
2. Token has all the required scopes/permissions for reporting. [Please click here to view the token permissions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Am5Bn.png)
3. The Account Id is correct for the app
4. I have the "Admin" access for the app as a Team Member.
5. The Campaign Id is correct and the Campaign is also in "Active" state.
6. The versioning in use is 202207
7. Did Fork the Reporting collection from the Linked-IN documentation and tried the API requests. It is also returning the same blank array response.
8. I'm also able to see the API requests Quotas & Usage. I'm able to see that the API requests are successfully linked to the App (please review the attached Screenshot) [Click here to review the screenshot of API requests at Linked-IN developer account](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lZnll.png)

This is my GET request:

[https://api.linkedin.com/rest/adAnalytics?q=analytics&pivot=CAMPAIGN&dateRange.start.day=1&dateRange.start.month=7&dateRange.start.year=2022&timeGranularity=DAILY&campaigns[0]=urn:li:sponsoredCampaign:{my_valid_campaign_id_of_9_digits}](https://api.linkedin.com/rest/adAnalytics?q=analytics&pivot=CAMPAIGN&dateRange.start.day=1&dateRange.start.month=7&dateRange.start.year=2022&timeGranularity=DAILY&campaigns%5B0%5D=urn:li:sponsoredCampaign:%7Bmy_valid_campaign_id_of_9_digits%7D)

I'm not able to get any campaign metrics/info from the API so far. Please help.

Comment: I'm still stuck with this issue. Haven't found any solution yet. One thing that I have observed so far is that I'm able to get response for those API services that do not require any scope and the APi's that require a scope permission are returning me blank array response and sometimes 404 and somes times access denied.

The strange part is my "Access Token" has all the required scopes (as shown above in the screenshot at point 2) for the API and my campaign's are also in "Active" state.

Quite strange. Has anyone faced such issue ? I think I should generate a new "Access Token" maybe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally today I was able to figure out the issue. It was due to lack of permission from the "Campaign Manager" dashboard. We have to assign a Role to our Linked-IN "app" from the "Campaign Manager" dashboard by going to the => Manage Access => Assign any one role to the app [Billing admin | Account manager | Campaign manager | Creative manager | Viewer] and that was all.